# Spatial equivalent of rbindlist?

Tags: r, rbind, r-sp, r-sf, rbindlist

I need to rbind, in a loop, a load of SpatialPolygonDataFrames . These are created by buffering a roads file. However as my 'roads' file of class SpatialLinesDataFrame is 15000 rows long, the rbind function gets progressively slower. If they were data frames I would use rblindlist to speed things up. But that doesn't work with sp objects (right?). Does anyone have a good idea?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(roads)) {

  temp <- gDifference(gBuffer(roads[i,], byid = T, width =  15, capStyle = 'ROUND'), 
                  gBuffer(roads[i,], byid = T, width =  10, capStyle = 'ROUND'))

  slot(slot(temp, "polygons")[[1]], "ID") <- as.character(roads[i,]$oid)

  if (i == 1) {difference <- temp}

  if (i > 1) {difference <- rbind(difference, temp)}

  rm(temp)
  print(i)

}
```

Thanks

James

Comment: Have you tried putting them into a list and doing `do.call(rbind, ListofSPDFs)` after the loop?

Comment: Hi Roland. I haven't . I will try that later. Though I like Tim's suggestion below so would like to pursue that first. Cheers again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you need to loop at all. You could use package `sf`. 
Here's an example of what (I think) you want to achieve:

```
library(mapview) # for the example lines data
library(sf)
trails$diff = st_geometry(st_buffer(trails, dist = 1500)) / st_geometry(st_buffer(trails, 1000))
mapview(trails$diff)
```

Is this your desired outcome? If not, you might want to provide an reproducible example.

Comment: Hi TimSalabim . Thanks for the answer. That looks really promising .... but doesn't actually work for me? I get the below error.

"Error in Ops.sfc(st_geometry(st_buffer(trails, dist = 1500)), st_geometry(st_buffer(trails,  : 
  operation / not supported"

I thought maybe it needs wrapping in st_difference ? But struggle with that too.

Comment: I thnk you need sf version 0.6.2 (latest CRAN) for that to work. See also [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/675) for some further info

Comment: Wow, amazing, thanks Tim. This has saved me LOADS of time.

Comment: `sf` really changed the way I approach spatial analyses. It is such a pleasant experience working with it and the API is well thought out in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's just taking some adjustment from my years of working with sp and PostGIS databases.

Comment: PS: If you've got a minute, you'll likely be able to help me with this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372533/changing-crs-of-a-sf-object

Comment: I've added a comment over there